# Marginalizing over a joint distribution

Tags: probability, machine-learning, bayesian, bayesian-network

I am trying to understand and answer the following:

> For the probability distribution $P(A, B, C, D)$ with the
>   factorization $P(A, B, C, D) = P(A)P(B)P(C|A, B)P(D|C)$, show that the
>   following conditional independence assumptions hold:
>
> (i) $A ⊥ B|∅$
>
> (ii) $A ⊥ D|C$

For the item (i), we want to show that $P(A,B)=P(A)P(B)$. As far as I see, I can do the following:

$P(A,B)=\sum\limits_{\forall C, D} P(A)P(B)P(C│A,B)P(D│C) = P(A)P(B)\sum\limits_{\forall C, D}P(C│A,B)P(D│C)$

But I am not sure if I can just drop the terms $P(C│A,B)$ and $P(D│C)$. I thought they could be dropped since both are distributions over the values $A,B$ and $C$, respectively. And, therefore, they sum up to 1.

I am not confident about this answer, am I missing something...? Or this is the right way to go?

Comment: So, have you begun to tackle part (ii) and show $P(A, D\mid C)=P(A\mid C)P(D\mid C)$ ?

Comment: @GrahamKemp, I'm still trying to figure out. Is this a good start? $P(A,D|C)=\dfrac{\sum_{\forall B}P(A,B,C,D)}{P(C)}$ ?

Comment: Yes, so $P(C)P(A,D\mid C) = P(A)\,\bigl(\sum_{\forall B} P(B)\,P(C\mid A,B)\bigr)\,P(D\mid C)$, and then ...

Comment: @GrahamKemp ...then this $\sum_{\forall B}P(B)P(C|A,B)$ can be written as $\dfrac{P(C,A)}{P(A)}$. So $P(A,D|C)=\dfrac{P(D|C)P(A|C)P(C)}{P(C)}=P(D|C)P(A|C)$. Confirm?

Comment: Yes, indeed, so.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your time @GrahamKemp :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, by rearranging the double sum, and using the Law of Total Probability:
$$\begin{align}\sum_{\forall C,D}\mathsf P(C\mid A,B)\,\mathsf P(D\mid C)&=\sum_{\forall C} \Bigl(\mathsf P(C\mid A,B)\sum_{\forall D} \mathsf P(D\mid C)\Bigr)\\[1ex] &= \sum_{\forall C}\mathsf P(C\mid A,B)\\[1ex] &= 1\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, it clarified :)